# Find matches on adjacent lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, perl

I want to find adjacent matching lines, e.g., if the pattern matches are

```
$ grep -n pattern file1 file2 file3
file1:10: ...
file2:100: ...
file2:1000: ...
file2:1001: ...
file3:1: ...
file3:123: ...
```

I want to find the middle two matches:

```
file2:1000: ...
file2:1001: ...
```

but not the first two and the last two.

Comment: How can "file2:1000" and "file2:1001" be "adjacent matching lines"?

Comment: What should happen if there are three matches in a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use the same test file as thrig:

```
$ cat file
a
pat 1
pat 2
b
pat 3
```

Here is an awk solution:

```
$ awk '/pat/ && last {print last; print} {last=""} /pat/{last=$0}' file
pat 1
pat 2
```

#### How it works

`awk` implicitly loops over every line in the file.  This program uses one variable, `last`, which contains the last line if it matched regex `pat`.  Otherwise, it contains the empty string.

- `/pat/ && last {print last; print}`

  If `pat` matches this line and the previous line, `last`, was also a match, then print both lines.
- `{last=""}`

  Replace `last` with an empty string
- `/pat/ {last=$0}`

  If this line matches `pat`, then set `last` to this line.  This way it will be available when we process the next line.

#### Alternative for treating >2 consecutive matches as one group

Let's consider this extended test file:

```
$ cat file2
a
pat 1
pat 2
b
pat 3
c
pat 4
pat 5
pat 6
d
```

Unlike the solution above, this code treats the three consecutive matching lines as one group to be printed:

```
$ awk '/pat/{f++; if (f==2) print last; if (f>=2) print; last=$0; next} {f=0}' file2
pat 1
pat 2
pat 4
pat 5
pat 6
```

This code uses two variables.  As before, `last` is the previous line.  In addition, `f` counts the number of consecutive matches.  So, we print matching lines when `f` is 2 or larger.

#### Adding grep-like features

To emulate the `grep` output shown in the question, this version prints the filename and line number before each matching line:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{f=0} /pat/{f++; if (f==2) printf "%s:%s:%s\n",FILENAME,FNR-1,last; if (f>=2) printf "%s:%s:%s\n",FILENAME,FNR,$0; last=$0; next} {f=0}' file file2
file:2:pat 1
file:3:pat 2
file2:2:pat 1
file2:3:pat 2
file2:7:pat 4
file2:8:pat 5
file2:9:pat 6
```

Awk's FILENAME variables provides the file's name and awk's `FNR` provides the line number within the file.

At the beginning of each file, `FNR==1`, we reset `f` to zero.  This prevents the last line of one file from being considered *consecutive* with the first line of the next file.

For those who like their code spread over multiple lines, the above looks like:

```
awk '
    FNR==1{f=0}
    /pat/ {f++
        if (f==2) printf "%s:%s:%s\n",FILENAME,FNR-1,last
        if (f>=2) printf "%s:%s:%s\n",FILENAME,FNR,$0
        last=$0
        next
    }

    {f=0}
    ' file file2
```

Comment: @don_crissti OK. I just updated with an approach that handles _two or more consecutive_ matches as one group to be printed.

Comment: @don_crissti  OK.  Answer updated with `grep`-like features.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to save the previous line, and print when the current and previous line both match:

```
bash-4.1$ (echo a; echo pat 1; echo pat 2; echo b; echo pat 3)
a
pat 1
pat 2
b
pat 3
bash-4.1$ (echo a; echo pat 1; echo pat 2; echo b; echo pat 3) | \
          perl -nle 'print "$prev\n$_" if /pat/ and $prev =~ /pat/; $prev=$_'
pat 1
pat 2
```

This will however result in duplicate matches should there be three or more adjacent lines that match, as these will match pairwise two or more times. A better option would be to keep track of the number of previous lines that match, and also to write some test code to confirm that the various fiddly edge cases (e.g. a block up against the end of the file) are handled properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $prev;
my $pattern = qr/pat/;
my $have_matches = 0;

while (my $line = readline) {
  if ($line =~ /$pattern/) {
    print $prev if $have_matches == 1;
    print $line if $have_matches;
    $have_matches++;
    $prev = $line;
  } else {
    $have_matches = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, you could also do this with `sed`:

```
sed -s '$!N
/.*PATTERN.*\n/{/\n.*PATTERN/{x;/^1$/!s/.*/1/;b v};//!{x;/^1$/{s/./0/;b v};//!D}}
//!{${/PATTERN/{x;/^1$/{b v}}};D;};: v;x;P;D' file1 file2 ... fileN
```

That's `gnu sed`. With other `sed`s you'd have to process one file at a time:

```
sed '$!N                   # if not on the last line pull in the next line
/.*PATTERN.*\n/{           # if first line in the pattern space matches
/\n.*PATTERN/{             # and if second line also matches                   
x                          # exchange pattern space with hold buffer
/^1$/!s/.*/1/              # replace everything with 1
b v                        # branch to label v
}
//!{                       # if second line does not match
x                          # exchange pattern space with hold buffer
/^1$/{                     # if it matches 1
s/.*/0/                    # replace with 0
b v                        # branch to label v
}
//!D                       # if it does not match 1 delete up to first newline
}
}
//!{                       # if first line does not match
${                         # if we're on the last line
/PATTERN/{                 # and if it matches
x                          # exchange pattern space with hold buffer
/^1$/{                     # if it matches 1
b v                        # branch to label v
}
}
}
D                          # else delete up to first newline
}
: v                        # label v
x                          # exchange pattern space with hold buffer
P                          # print up to first newline
D' infile                  # delete up to first newline
```

It's not as flexible as `perl` or `awk` though - you can't fully emulate `grep` output i.e. prefix lines with the file name and line number though with `gnu sed` you could get the filename by adding `F` before the `P` and then piping the entire output to `paste -d: - -`

Comment: Very impressive sed-fu.  +1.

Answer (score -2):

Hi there are various command which can help you fine last line try this..

```
<grep command> | tail -1
```

or

```
awk '/result/ { save=$0 }END{ print save }' filename
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that this answer is irrelevant (as suggested by @don_crissti)